# overwrite 0x00 into a file C

Tags: c, fwrite

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int size;

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("prova" , "rb");

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("%s",strerror(2));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
/* Controllo lunghezza file */
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size=ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
/* --- */
for(i=1; i<=size; i++){
    qualcosa
}
fclose(fp);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to "secure delete" a file by overwriting it with 0x00...like what /dev/zero do!
How can i do it?
I've opened the file, i've check his lenght...and now?

Comment: Opening a file and writing its length in NUL bytes does not securely delete the file; most OS's do not guarantee that what you're writing will be written to the same disk sectors that the file originally occupied.

Comment: Yes i know but a file that have been overwritten is not recoverable. Filesystem like ext3,4 HFS, btrfs, NTFS, etc recovert the metadata of file, no the contenent...

Comment: true that the file itself may not be recoverable intact, but you specifically asked to "securely" delete, implying that the data being deleted is of a sensitive nature. If there is a (good) chance that the data itself is lurking about in unlinked sectors, you have done your client a disservice by providing a false sense of security.

Comment: Found this for you: http://techthrob.com/2009/03/02/howto-delete-files-permanently-and-securely-in-linux/

Comment: i've already known shred and wipe ;)

Comment: however i know that it isn't so secure as it could be wipe or shred but this is only a personal project :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you're only opening it for reading:

```
fp=fopen("prova" , "rb");
```

You need:

```
fp=fopen("prova" , "w+");
```

After that, you just need to write zeroes to the file until you've hit the length you've already determined using `fputc()` or `fwrite()`

It occurs to me though that this really may not solve your actual problem depending on the OS. It may end up writing the file to a different area on the disk (thus leaving your original data untouched)